# NameError: name 'tstats_df' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to perform 2 sample t-test on all categorical variables and wanted this result for every categorical variable:

```
## Numerical Variabletstats_df = pd.DataFrame()
for num_list in data_num:
    tstats = stats.ttest_ind(credit_risk[credit_risk['default']==1][num_list],credit_risk[credit_risk['default']==0][num_list])

    temp = pd.DataFrame([num_list, tstats[0], tstats[1]]).T

    temp.columns = ['Variable Name', 'T-Statistic', 'P-Value']

    tstats_df = pd.concat([tstats_df, temp], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(tstats_df)
```

> expected :-
>   Variable Name     T-Statistic      P-Value
>   error :-
>   NameError: name 'tstats_df' is not defined

Comment: As per the above shared code, it seems that you are trying to concatenate the data frames without initializing them first. So if you want to continue with your code, please try this change  tstats_df = pd.DataFrame([])    tstats_df = pd.concat([tstats_df, temp], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

Comment: `pd.concat([tstats_df, temp], axis=0, ignore_index=True)` here tstats_df is a DataFRame which is not defined before this line. This is the reason you are getting `NameError`